# how to find whether speakerphone is on or not in android

Tags: android

i need to find whether speaker phone is on or not through programmability.

I know that we can find using below method whether it is on or not.

```
AudioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn();
```

in my case even it is returning false, even though the speaker is on by some how.

I need to know below 2 things.

1.is there any broadcast action to find speaker state.

2.is there any way to find speaker phone state change

Comment: How are you getting you AudioManager. I hope you are getting from your application context. (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);  If yes, then it should work. (its a system wide service and you are not asked to meddle with it unless your application is handling telephony et a)

Comment: yes, actually the case is once the voice call is connected i am starting my application. in this case speaker is switching on. is there any thing relating with telephony now. can u please suggest

Comment: I think you should use the broadcast receiver, as displayed here: [ Ringer mode change listener Broadcast receiver][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483961/ringer-mode-change-listener-broadcast-receiver

Answer (score 0):

Try this for speaker ON functionality.

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) Home.this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);
audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link. Might be useful.

[Turn on speakerphone whenever an outgoing call is made](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8617381/turn-on-speakerphone-whenever-an-outgoing-call-is-made/21328490#21328490)

But the link does not use broadcast reciever. It only checks if the speaker feature is on or not at that instant.

Answer (score 0):

Here you Go

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) MainActivity.this .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);

    if(audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn()){
        audioManager.setSpeakerphoneOn(true);


    }else if(!audioManager.isSpeakerphoneOn()){


    }
```