# how to get ringer mode in android application

Tags: android

iam making application  will changes from silent mode to ringer mode if the specific user call.   The application mainly convert from silent to normal or normal to silent. My main question is how can i get the previous state(ringer mode)??... the previous mean the state before convert mode because i need to back to this state when idle ... plz help me 
visit[Ringer mode change listener Broadcast receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483961/ringer-mode-change-listener-broadcast-receiver)?

Answer (score 1):

Use  AudioManager.getRingerMode() before changing it.

Comment: then compare this with new state to return for previous ?????