# How to Detect the Android Phone Speaker playing any sound

Tags: android

I want to detect if the Android Phone speaker is in use by any App like whether Music Player is playing Music or Alarm is Ringing or Video is playing. I dont want to detect just if a specific App is using the Ringer all i want to do is get Notified if the Ringer is used by Any APP.

Comment: use `isMusicActive()` in your service

Comment: isMusicActive can be used only for the music Player. i want to check any activity on the ringer @Praveen

Comment: create a broadcast receiver for phone ringer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7483961/ringer-mode-change-listener-broadcast-receiver

Comment: @JibranKhan that is just for the ringer when someone is calling you. I need to check if anything (i.e any app, system apps , music , video) is using the Phone Ringer